# errors occurred while compiling on gcc

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a,b,sub,i,count=0;char buffer[20],w[20];
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    sub=a-b;
    if(sub>0)
    {
        scanf("%s",w); /*wrong answer*/
        itoa(sub,buffer,10);
        int l=strlen(buffer);
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(w[i]==buffer[i])
                count++;
        }
        ((count==l || count==l-1) && w[0]!='0') ? printf("accepted") : printf("Not accepted");
    }
    else printf("Sub operation returned negative value");
}
```

The output of the compiler is

```
prog.c:4:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
 void main(void)
      ^
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:13:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'itoa' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 itoa(sub,buffer,10);
 ^
/home/HCDVgj/ccHBnrc7.o: In function `main':
prog.c:(.text.startup+0x61): undefined reference to `itoa'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I did not use any long int variables but i still get ld return 1 exists. how to debug these errors

Comment: 1) Fix the return type of main. It's not relevant to the question, but is just bad practice IMO. 2) How did you build your program?

Comment: It's not 'the output of this program'. Your program does not make any output, because it does not run. It's output of a compiler.

Comment: Read your **warnings** they spell it out. See [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 2):

- `int main()` This is teh first thing you should do.
- `scanf("%19s",w);`  This is better.
- `itoa` is non standard (so you will not find it in any standard implementaion) better use `snprintf()`
- `printf('%s",((count==l || count==l-1) && w[0]!='0') ? "accepted" : "Not accepted");` More compact I would say.

### Use of `snprintf`

`snprintf(target, size_of_target`<sup>1</sup>`, "%d", source`<sup>2</sup>`);`

`sprintf` takes no parameter specifying the number of bytes to write which may lead to buffer overflow which is not a good thing.

<sub>1 : In bytes</sub> 
<sub>2 : source is in integer here</sub>

### Few things worth mentioning to clear your idea or to be more precise

- The output you specified is not output of the c program ... in the process of compilation your compiler run into error and then it generates those output. -**<sub>CiaPan</sub>**
- `main()` shouldn't be of void return type it is expected to return `0` in case of normal termination. Abnormal termination is usually signaled by a non-zero.-**<sub>David C. Rankin</sub>**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're talking about "long int variables".

The first warning can be fixed by changing `void main(void)` to `int main(void)` and adding a `return 0;` at the end.

The second warning tells you that the compiler doesn't know what `itoa` is.

The following linker error tells you that the linker (`ld`) also doesn't know what `itoa` is, and that's why compilation fails.

The reason `itoa` is unknown is that it's not a standard function and not available on your platform.